# How to send dynamic template mail via guzzle HTTP in PHP

Tags: php, guzzle, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to send an email via Dynamic template in SendGrid using Guzzle HTTP in PHP.

But I was not able to send mail. As I get only the error like below without any reason in it.

```
Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException

Message: Client error: `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

My PHP example code:

```
require __DIR__.'../../vendor/autoload.php';
$CLIENT = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $CLIENT->request('POST', 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send', [
    "headers" => [
        "Authorization" => "Bearer my-api-key",
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    ],
    'data' => '{
      "from": {
        "email": "admin@example.com"
      },
      "personalizations": [{
        "to": [{
          "email": "me@gmail.com"
        }],
        "dynamic_template_data": {
          "email_data": [{
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Artificial Intelligence in Health Care",
            "image": "https://example.com//uploads/3663581583995181_0724.jpg",
            "description": "Immediate application of AI in the Health Care domains."
          }, {
            "id": "199",
            "title": "Aesthetics Skill Discussion 3 by Jranand",
            "image": "",
            "description": "Aesthetics Skill Discussion 3 by Jranand"
          }]
        }
      }],
      "template_id": "my-template-id"
    }',
]);

echo $response->getStatusCode();
```

**I was able to send an email via the dynamic template test method in SendGrid with the same dynamic_template_data. But trying this with Guzzle HTTP. I m not able to find the reason for the error.**

Able to send an email with dynamic JSON data in the testing.

[image: test method]

Can anyone help me out to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll be that guy here and point out that the [Sendgrid PHP Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) does exist and is pretty darn good.

Comment: why are you using data key I guess that is where it is wrong, you want to send json I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **data** request option in json, you need to change your code either you can use **json** request option from guzzle(will need lesser effort) or you can directly right your body.

```
try{
  
  $CLIENT = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$data = [
        "from" => [
                "email" => "admin@example.com"
            ],
        "personalizations" => [
                [
                    "to" =>  [
                        [
                          "email" => "me@gmail.com"
                        ]    
                    ],
                    "dynamic_template_data" => [
                        "email_data" => [
                            [
                                "id" => "2",
                                "title" => "Artificial Intelligence in Health Care",
                                "image" => "https://example.com//uploads/3663581583995181_0724.jpg",
                                "description"=> "Immediate application of AI in the Health Care domains." 
                            ],
                            [
                                "id" => "199",
                                "title" => "Aesthetics Skill Discussion 3 by Jranand",
                                "image" => "",
                                "description" => "Aesthetics Skill Discussion 3 by Jranand"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        "template_id" => "my-template-id"
            
    ];
$response = $CLIENT->request('POST', 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send', [
    "headers" => [
        "Authorization" => "Bearer my-api-key",
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    ],
    'json'  => $data,
]);

    if ($guzzleResponse->getStatusCode() == 200) {
         $response = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody(),true);
         //perform your action with $response 
    } 
}
catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e){
   // you can catch here 400 response errors and 500 response errors and log those errors
   
}catch(Exception $e){
   //other errors 
}
```